# DAX measure for adding a polynomial trendline to a line chart in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I would like to try to add a polynomial trendline to a line chart in Power BI Desktop.  Currently, the stock "linear trendline" is not much value in my chart, due to all the peaks and valleys.  Is there some DAX code/measure that can accomplish this?

I tried using LINEST and LINESTX but could not get either one to work (i.e. - produce the curved trendline)